# How to merge separated object no loose

Tags: vertices, cloth-simulation

If I do cloth simulation using 3D model below, it break up because the model is separated with blue line.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I want to merge each parts of model, what is the best way to solve this problem??

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly it looks like your cloth simulation has nothing to collide with and therefore just collapses onto your plane.  I don't think those sharp edges are your problem.

Comment: @MarkGrant no, it’s that the cloth is actually breaking up. It looks like to me that the sharp edges are also split edges.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see it now. You actually want crumpled trousers on the floor.  Apologies.  You seem to have an answer that could work though now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting all, and then use merge by distance. Vertices that are in the same location will be connected. If this does not solve your problem, you could use bridge edge loops possibly and then degenerate dissolve.

Comment: Thank you for your help!